# Two way repeated measures ANOVA with varying repetition

Tags: anova

I measure the response to two different stimuli. For one stimulus measurements were taken three times and the other stimulus they were taken twice. Is it possible to do two way repeated measures ANOVA? If not, what are the alternatives? Thank you.

Comment: Does it make sense to consider only two measurements for each stimuli?

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to analyze all the measurements.